# microsoft ftp update remote file date

Tags: ftp, file-manager

Is there a way to change the file date throw ftp connection on remote server?

as the file is uploaded it sets create date to the date it was uploaded, and i want the file to keep its original date time.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is the server with the FTP actually creates the file.  The same would be the case if you uploaded a file using an upload form on a web page.  A workaround would be to create a java or active x control to upload docs.  This control could read the create date from the files metadata and store it in a db.  Its not an elegant approach, but how most backup services go about it.